# How to create a plot of the volume between three surfaces

Tags: graphics

I need help creating a plot that I can manipulate the variables for the  volume between three surfaces. I am trying to make it look like this example here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExploringCylindricalCoordinates/ but with the volume I need.

It is volume that lies within the cylinder x^2+y^2=1, above the plain z=0 ,and below the cone z^2=4x^2+4y^2. I converted to cylindrical coordinates (z,r,theta). Here is what I have so far.:

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[2 r, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2}]]
```

thank you

Comment: You could tag on triangles in the y=0 plane and the half-disk floor in the z=0 plane, not sure if that's good enough :)

Comment: no  i don't know how to do that but thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For the static plot in the question, the missing pieces are two triangular walls in the y=0 plane an a half-disk floor in the z=0 plane

```
Show[
 (* Put the half-disk floor in here, just a constant 0 function *)
 RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}}, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2}],
 (* And the triangles here *)
 Graphics3D[{
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}}],
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 2}}]
   }],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: output]

You can parameterize the triangles too of course:

```
Show[
 RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}}, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, Pi}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{
   {Cos[u], Sin[u], v},
   u/Pi {1, 0, v},
   u/Pi {-1, 0, v}
   }, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much you are the man!! i really appropriate it. hopefully I'm not asking too much of you but could you point me in the right direction for adding the variable sliders to the graph. Will the "Manipulate" command do it or is there another method?

Comment: @user10977 `Manipulate` is the tool for the job. Hint to generalize the triangles: The second triangle parametrization in this case can be written as `u/Pi { Cos[Pi], Sin[Pi], v}`

Comment: great i'm trying it now

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand Manipulate[
 Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}}, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, 
    u/Pi {Cos[Pi], Sin[Pi], v}}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> All], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {{r, 1}, 0, 2}, {{u, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{v, 0}, 0, 
  2}]

Comment: @user10977 There you have one Manipulate variable called `v` and one `ParametricPlot3D` variable called  `v` that easily gets confusing for both humans and mathematica, perhaps call the `Manipulate` variable `vmax` and make the `ParametricPlot3D` range `{v, 0, vmax}`

Comment: You could put the cylinder in the `RevolutionPlot3D` instead of having a separate `ParametricPlot3D` - use `{{2 r}, {0}, {1, 2 r}}`

Comment: to ssch I'm too new to this software to understand you help. i did try though i got an error. i still thank you though.     Manipulate[
 Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}}, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u/Pi, 
     0, (2 u)/Pi v/2}, {-u/Pi, 0, (2 u)/Pi v/2}}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 
    vmax}, PlotRange -> All], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {{r, 1}, 0, 2}, {{u, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{vmax, 0}, 0,
   2}]

Comment: to Simon Thank you for your suggestion but i think I'm missing something i get en error. I don't think mathematica is meant for calculus at least not solids of revolution or use cylindrical coordinates problems since it feels like I'm forcing or tricking the software to do something it is not made to do natively.  the interactive 3Dplot i am trying to make like the one up there must be trick example.    Manipulate[RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}, {1, 2 r}}, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
 PlotRange -> All, {{r, 1}, 0, 2}, {{u, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{v, 0}, 0, 2}]

Comment: @user10977 Play with this and see if you can figure out how/why it works: `Manipulate[
 Show[
  RevolutionPlot3D[{{2 r}, {0}, {rmax, 2 r}}, {r, 0, rmax}, {theta, 0,
     tmax}],
  ParametricPlot3D[
   {
     r {1, 0, 2 v},
    r {Cos[tmax], Sin[tmax], 2 v  }
    },
   {r, 0, rmax}, {v, 0, 1}]
  , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
  , PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 10}}
  , BoxRatios -> 1],
 {{tmax, Pi}, 0.1, 2 Pi},
 {{rmax, 1}, 0.1, 5}]`

Comment: Amazing ssch thank you all praises to you. I still feel that the combination of RevolutionPlot3D and ParametricPlot3D is not the way to go for plotting solids of revolution. But what do i know i'm still learning. again thank you.

Comment: @user10977 Yea, would be nice with a `Filling` option for `RevolutionPlot3D`